# Component using React Factory not getting rendered

Tags: reactjs

I tried this simple component using React Factory, but the output in browser is blank. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Pure React Samples</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Target Container -->
<div id="react-container"></div>
<! -- React Library & React DOM -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.2/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.4.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script>
    const simpleComponent = () => React.DOM.h1(null, 'Baked Salmon')

    const myfactory = React.createFactory(simpleComponent)

    ReactDOM.render(myfactory,document.getElementbyId("react-container"))
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*Edit* This code works fine without converting the component to element.

```
const IngredientsList = (list) => React.DOM.h1(null, 'Baked Salmon')

const Ingredients = React.createFactory(IngredientsList)

const list = {}

ReactDOM.render(Ingredients(list), document.getElementById('react-container'))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1. Change `document.getElementbyId` to `document.getElementById`.
2. `ReactDOM.render` function expects a `React element` but `React.createFactory` returns a component. So you need to convert that component to element. You can use `React.createElement` function for that

   ```
   const simpleComponent = () => React.DOM.h1(null, 'Baked Salmon')

   const myfactory = React.createFactory(simpleComponent)

   ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(myfactory) ,document.getElementbyId("react-container"))
   ```

https://jsfiddle.net/m19k4p08/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ById. However, the following code works fine without converting component to element.                                const IngredientsList = (list) => React.DOM.h1(null, 'Baked Salmon')

 const Ingredients = React.createFactory(IngredientsList)

 const list = {}

 ReactDOM.render(Ingredients(list), document.getElementById('react-container'))

Comment: What am I missing?

Comment: Please update your question with code. Dont post in comment.

Comment: @KrishnanRavikumar Because `Ingredients` is a component but `Ingredients(list)` return the element.